# Custom rule based on two value

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have the following data model: Region (id, name, countries_id, tag). The tag is unique and it's composed of name + countries_id. For example:

```
name=Arizona 
countries_id=us 
tag=arizona-us
```

The name and countries_id values are attached in the request data but, tag value must be unique and is generated dinamically.

I want create a validation rule that validates the uniqueness property of tag value.

My code is:

```
return array(
    'name' => ['required', new RegionUniqueRule()],
    'countries_id' => ['required', 'exists:mysql.countries,id'],
);

class Regionunique implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $countriesIdValue = 'COUNTRIES_ID VALUE !!!';
        $text = sprintf('%s %s', $value, $countriesIdValue);
        $table = DB::table('regions');
        $table->where('tag', str_slug($text));
        return ($table->first() === null);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The region already exists';
    }
}
```

So, how i can get the countries_id value inside of Regionunique ?

Comment: Where is the code that actually run the validator?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a input before validate, like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Override Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::initialize.
     * After parent::initialize, run beforeValidation
     */
    public function initialize(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), array $attributes = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null)
    {
         parent::initialize($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
         $this->beforeValidation();
    }

    protected function beforeValidation()
    {
         //implement in child class
    }
}

class MyRequest extends Request
{
    protected function beforeValidation()
    {
         $tag = sprintf('%s %s', $this->input('name'), $this->input('countries_id'));
         $this->merge([
             'tag' => $tag,
         ]);
    }

     public function rules()
     {
         return array(
              'name' => ['required'],
              'countries_id' => ['required', 'exists:mysql.countries,id'],
              'tag' => ['required','unique'],
         );
     }
} 


class MyController
{
     public function myMethod(MyRequest $request)
     {
          //do something
     }
}
```

Here we create a new Request abstract class, that override `initialize(..)`  function from framework. After initialized, the base class call `beforeValidation()` to run anything before the validation. Then we insert a new input value `tag` to the input array, and validate against `unique` rule.